# How can I add the result of a transformed batch to the original item set?

Tags: msbuild

I have an MSBuild script which uses a custom task to extract the version information from AssemblyInfo files:

```
<GetAssemblyInfo
    AssemblyInfoFiles="@(WebProject->
        '%(RootDir)%(Directory)Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs')">
    <Output TaskParameter="AssemblyInfo" ItemName="AssemblyInfo"/>
</GetAssemblyInfo>
```

This produces a new set of items which contain the information I need as further metadata.

At this point, I don't know how to associate the metadata back to the to source items `WebProject`. Conceptually they're related to each other by path, as expressed by the original transform `%(RootDir)%(Directory)Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs`.

I've tried to use various combinations of MSBuild batching syntax, but each one seems further from where I want to be than the last.

I'm very new to batching with MSBuild, so any examples are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to get the set I wanted in a single step, but this solution does produce the output I require.

Create a cross-join product of all the projects and assembly versions. Additionally include the directory the AssemblyInfo file located in.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <VersionedProject Include="@(WebProject)">
        <Version>%(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyFileVersion)</Version>
        <AssemblyInfoDir>
            %(AssemblyInfo.RootDir)%(AssemblyInfo.Directory)
        </AssemblyInfoDir>
    </VersionedProject>
```

Then remove all items where the properties directory is not the location of the AssemblyInfo file.

```
    <VersionedProject
        Remove="@(VersionedProject)"
        Condition="'%(RootDir)%(Directory)Properties\' != '%(AssemblyInfoDir)'"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

The following outputs a correct list of project names and version numbers.

```
<Message Text="%(VersionedProject.Filename): %(VersionedProject.Version)" />
```